# Small bump in my 15" MacBook Pro 2018

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard

I finally upgraded from my old MBP 2015 and got the 2018 15" base model. So far I'm in love with this machine, clean thin design and very performant (the addition of a 6 core CPU and DDR4 RAMS is much welcome).

However, there's one issue that I can't figure out if it's just me or it's something to do with the machine. Whenever I look at my keyboard, It feels like it's raised a little bit in the top middle kinda like there's a small bump. I showed it to my friends, some seem to notice it and some don't. Some are saying that it's just an optical illusion.

Has anyone come across any information to suggest this is a known issue? If so, what?

Answer (score 1):

Here’s how I would try to figure this out.

if you have a straight edge, perhaps a 12" metal ruler, try laying that ***ON EDGE*** across the keyboard at the bottom, top, and middle, and perhaps even a couple diagonal angles. I'm not sure if the newer models are like mine at home, but the keys rest just ever-so-slightly below the case, so you should be able to see if anything is approaching the ruler's edge across the span.

if you're unable to tell, something like this could probably warrant a pic or two added here, or even if just taken from your phone, which could then be examined by eye and perhaps by selection in a photo editing app. it wouldn't be 100% accurate, but if there was an upward shift of pixels in the middle versus the two ends, you might have something.

either way, better to be sure now while under warranty, so you can at least get it on notice in case it gets worse. if it's related to heat, or perhaps some sort of battery swelling, it might be more noticeable at certain times. I've had several batteries expand over the years, and I believe they all stayed the bloated width, but before they became damaging or even just noticeable, they might have swelled and reverted, I can't say.